# What font does Prada use for their logo?

Tags: font-identification

What's the name of the font? I am working in this picture so I want know the font name.

[image]

Comment: have you tried googling "prada font"? Because that has some rather precise results...

Comment: https://deltafonts.com/prada-font/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are fonts similar to Prada's logo such as [Engravers Roman Bold BT](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/engravers-roman/bold/testdrive.html?s=PRADA&p=72) (the A is different) however the Prada 'font' is not available as it was developed for the brand alone, though it seems to be from the family 'Agfa-Monotype' as mentioned in another answer on a different site [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=109128).

There has been talk of making it a font though rather than needing to rasterize the alphabet that is found [here](http://alias.dj/blog/candy/) if you desperately wanted it and of course it's for somethinglike a project in college rather than commercial use.

It was requested a couple of times in 2012 (see [here](http://www.dafont.com/forum/read/77475/what-the-font-prada)) though Idon't think anything better than [this](http://www.typetoken.net/typeface/prada-candy-typeface-by-gareth-hague-alias/) was created.

Good luck with your work!